# How do php frameworks protect action script/dataservice files?

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller

I'm wondering how frameworks keep a user from directly accessing the action / dataservice script.

For example we go to `www.test.com/test.html` template `test.html` invokes **`test_action.php`**. What is stopping a user from going to the directory where this action script lives directly?

Such as `www.test.com/index/actions/test_action.php`

How are server permissions configured, so that **`test_action.php`** is accessed only through `test.html`.

- in the case where I am stuck in doc-root on a shared hosting server
- in the case where I'm running the show ~ I.E. my apache server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do nothing, and test_action.php is under your docroot, the use can access it. There are several ways to deal with this, if that is not acceptable (note that if your server has PHP properly installed/configured, they will *not* see the source code, just the output of the source code).

If it is not allowable for the user to see the output of that script directly, you can choose one of several methods:

1. Place all *protected* scripts *outside* the docroot of your HTTP server, then reference them using ../includes or similar
2. [Use an apache access control](http://www.techiecorner.com/1245/how-to-block-access-to-certain-file-types-using-htaccess/) file to deny requests to .php (cut it off at the pass).
3. Make an file called `entry.php` which declares a global constant, then include that file first from all of your *valid* entry points, and then in each of your *protected* scripts, check for the presence of that constant (IIRC, this is what CodeIgniter does).

Generally, #1 is recommended. If that's not good, #2 is very efficient, and #3 is, IMO, just tacky.

Comment: please see edits. I need just a little bit more info for shared hosting case.

Comment: option 2 and 3 here are available in a shared situation as long as your host allows .htaccess to have this control, which it *should* (i.e. if it doesn't, get a new host). Then of course option 1 is for when you do have control.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked how php frameworks handle this issue, there are two common ways:

- **the proper way**:

  Keeping all the code outside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Basically you have a `/public` folder, which contains just `index.php` , which then contains `include '../application/init.php`'.

  All the other php files are placed outside `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and are not directly accessible.
- **the stupid way**

  They define a constant in `index.php` file, and all the rest files begin with:

  ```
    defined('SOMETHING') or die('No direct script access.');
  ```

  This obviously will fail, if php extension on the server goes *tits-up*. You will end up with your php source visible to everyone.

*BTW*, I would not recommend using any apache-specific way for dealing with this issue, because you cannot be sure on which webserver will your framework be used. Both NginX and Lighttpd are becoming quite popular. An there is always IIS too.

Comment: please see edits. I need just a little bit more info for shared hosting case.

Comment: @DanKanze , if you are using shared hosting, then the security of your source code depends on the security of the hosting itself. Also, there is no rule which prevents shared hosting to implement the setup described in 1st point. In a good shared hosting you have as minimum `/logs` and `/www` folders .. there should be nothing preventing you from addition more folders.